# SQL Server: WHERE clause to ignore blank GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE CASE WHEN @ActivityUID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
    THEN
        -- do nothing
    ELSE
        (Activity.ActivityUID = @ActivityUID)
    END
```

When a blank Guid is passed in via ActivityUID then I want the WHERE statement to ignore `Activity.ActivityUID = @ActivityUID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE (
         Activity.ActivityUID = @ActivityUID OR 
         @ActivityUID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes the need for an OR clause because NULL comparisons fail.

```
WHERE
    Activity.ActivityUID = NULLIF(@ActivityUID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

See if there is a performance difference...